# Does contacts of type "HiddenTriggeredSend” count against contact limit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, contact

Does anybody know if contacts of type "HiddenTriggeredSend”" count against the limit of contacts purchased? We are not sure as the contact appears twice in 'All contacts' list but the All contacts count doesnt match the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not familiar with this help article, I would start there: [Contact Definition and Count Determination](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5)

Quick answer is yes these are counted as contact, but the contacts are dedupe by contactkey:

> Contact Deduplication
>   Contacts count only one time. Marketing Cloud automatically deduplicates multiple instances of a contact in a population based on the Contact Key value. For example, two records with different Contact Key values and the email address jai@example.com count as two unique contacts.

Comment: Hmm that is interesting. I am assuming 'HiddenTriggeredSend' is the type set for when you do a Trigger and do not have 'add to list' set so they are not added to allsubs, etc.  I heard that those people do not count towards your Contact Count as they are not added into anything you are able to access as a user, but instead into a hidden table behind the scenes specifically made just for this case. I have nothing to back this up, just wanted to make note and see if that is definitively wrong.

Comment: That is true it is a list to manage subscriber status for TriggeredSends that you don't want added to the All subs but they do count as contacts. You can currently see them in "All Contacts" with type "Hidden Triggered Send (3)" and you can delete them by using the subid or making an api call with contacttype = 3

Comment: Thanks for the info @EazyE